# JSF outputLink not appearing as a clickable URL link

Tags: html, jsf, url, href, jsf-2.2

I have a URL as a string stored as an attribute in a class, and I am trying to retrieve it through EL in the outputLink like below:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{flagData.countries}" var="country"
            styleClass="table table-striped table-hover" border="1">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                #{country.name}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Flag</f:facet>
                <h:outputLink value="#{country.flag}"></h:outputLink>
                #{country.flag}
            </h:column> 
</h:dataTable>
```

But this isn't working.

I want the URL stored in `#{country.flag}` to be a clickable URL link. How do I do this?

**EDIT:**

This is the generated html:

```
<td>
                Argentina
            </td>
<td><a href="http://www.flags-and-anthems.com/flag-argentina.html" class="btn btn-link"></a>
                http://www.flags-and-anthems.com/flag-argentina.html
            </td>
```

Comment: Did you check how the generated HTML output looks like? Does it look all right? Hint: This is not a JSF specific problem. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using plain vanilla HTML the same way.

Comment: @BalusC, oh yes I remember that. The solution had to do with using the class for the CSS bootstrap template I was using for my web app. thanks

Comment: @BalusC, that was last year. How did you remember that?

Comment: @BalusC, actually removing the CSS didn't work. Here is the source that is generated: `<td>
    Belgium
       </td>
<td><a href="http://www.flags-and-anthems.com/flag-belgium.html"></a>
                http://www.flags-and-anthems.com/flag-belgium.html
            </td>`

Comment: "You'd" stands for "You would". And, does the generated HTML output look all right? The link's body is actually empty, right?

Comment: @BalusC please see edit above. Seems like in the `<td>` tag where `href` is stored the body isn't empty

Comment: Surely it is empty. Look once again, the text you want to appear in the link is displayed outside `<a>` element and not inside (its body).

Comment: @BalusC hmm that's strange that the link isn't clickable. let me try making a simple html file with `href`

Comment: How would you solve it if you were to edit the plain HTML code? Once you figure out that, it's merely a matter of doing exactly the same in JSF side (so that it generates exactly the desired HTML output).

Comment: @BalusC oh wow, `#{country.flag}` had to go inside inside `<outputLink>`. Wonder how I missed that, seems obvious thinking about it

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the url you want to render as a clickable URL inside the tag

```
<h:outputLink value="#{country.flag}">#{country.flag}</h:outputLink>
```

the value of the output link is the url you will reach and the content of the tag is the text you have to click on